# How to deal with a border-color that might be similar to a background color?

Tags: css, colors

I have run into a minor issue with a jQuery UI web app that I am currently creating. In the app I am showing one of many preview screens which have elements - images, spans, paragraphs - that can be altered. When the mouse hovers over alterable elements I use class:hover to show a dotted red border so the user knows that they can click on the element to alter it.

All right thus far. The trouble starts because some of the preview screens use color schemes that include red backgrounds which make my :hover dotted red border all but invisible. Perhaps there is a smart CSS way to use a border color that shows up irrespective of the underlying background color?

Comment: Just pick a different color? Aren't you in control of the background colors being used? Or use a different color just for those that have a red background via a second class or something. It's either too broad/open for us to answer for you, or we need more detail about your specific scenario/code to provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a bit but couldn't find a satisfactory solution. So I figured that what mattered was to make the element "tactile" in some way.  In the end I set up

```
{
 -moz-transform:scale(0.75);-o-transform:scale(0.75);-webkit-transform:scale(0.75);
 opacity:1;filter:alpha(opacity=100)
}
```

Comment: You need to indent your code blocks with four spaces at the start of each line in order for them to show up as code. I've edited it for you.

Comment: Well, it is my own answer so in a manner of speaking it solved the problem.  However, that does not change the fact that it would still be neat if there were a way to use CSS to show up a red border against a red background (for red read any color you like) by somehow modifying it dynamically.  So this question is still open